# How do I combine figures in powerapps?

Tags: powerapps

I want to create an overlay on my main screen in powerapps as depicted in te figure below. In other Microsoft programs (i.e PowerPoint) there is a possibility to combine/merge/Fragment etc. shapes to create the depicted shape. How can I do this in Powerapps? Is there another way to create such an overlay?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to create a PP presentation?  Or do you want to embed an interactive webpage into a Word/Excel/PowerPoint doc?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a presentation of your Powerapp in PowerPoint.  You would be better off making a video demo and inserting that.  Press the windows key and the letter "G" to open up the game bar.  It has a built in screen recorder.

On the other hand if you are trying to embed the Powerapp (i.e. the webpage of your app in an iframe).  There are a few options.  None I have tested.  Search your office app for "embed webpage" or "iframe".

I found this one:
[image]